# Select rows with a duplicate ID but different value in another column

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table like this

[image]

I would like to select the Itemid that occurs more than once with a different Rate with group by Masterid

The output should be something like:

[image]

Comment: Please follow these suggestions when asking SQL questions https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2977/36809

Answer (score 1):

```
select tlt.* from table_like_this tlt
  where exists (select masterid, itemid from (
     select distinct masterid, itemid, rate from table_like_this) tlt2
     where tlt2.masterid = tlt.masterid
       and tlt2.itemid   = tlt.itemid
     group by masterid, itemid
     having count(*) > 1);
```

See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e09c6647c4c5c04a8013125e83090ec6

PS. images of data are completely useless.

Answer (score -1):

```
select * 
from (
    select masterid, itemid, detailid, dense_rank()over( order by itemid desc)rk 
    from testorder
    group by masterid, itemid, detailid
    )d 
where rk=3
order by masterid asc
```

Comment: It would be helpful to explain how this answers the question.

Comment: is it wrong approach??